# Redirect to page in form submit and use the form data in new page

Tags: 7, database, forms

How to redirect in drupal 7 in form submission, I need to use the submitted data in next redirected page but below `video_subtitle_view` function is not printing anything

How do i do it

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 * 
 */ 
function video_subtitles_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['player/video_subtitle/view'] = array(
     'page callback' => 'video_subtitle_view',
     'access callback' => 'user_access',
     'access arguments' => array('administer video_subtitles status'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

---

```
    function video_subtitle_view($form, &$form_state){
    //    print 'video_subtitle_view';
        print_r($form);
        print_r($form_state);
    }
```

---

```
function video_upload_subtitles_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

     $form_state['redirect'] = 'player/video_subtitle/view';
//     $form_state['redirect'] = array(
//            'player/video_subtitle/view',
//             array(
//                    'query' => array(
//                    'form' => $form,
//                    'form_state' => &$form_state,   
//                   ),
//              ),
//      );

}
```

---

```
function video_subtitle_view($form, &$form_state){
//    print 'video_subtitle_view';
    print_r($form);
    print_r($form_state);
}
```

do i need to pass the form data as parameter??

Comment: you can put form state into server session and then can use it on next page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use server session to keep your form state something like below

```
function video_upload_subtitles_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $_SESSION['my_form_data'] = $form_state;
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'player/video_subtitle/view';

}

// Then

function video_subtitle_view(){
    print_r($_SESSION['my_from_data']);
}
```